# Waiting for function with a setTimeout to complete without tampering with that function

Tags: javascript

So basically I have a function that has a `setTimeout` within it like so:

```
function foo(){
    console.log('starting');
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('done');
    }, 2000); // some arbitrary delay
}
```

and I want to call this function, have it truly complete, and then call a second function when it has ended:

```
foo();
secondFunction();
```

Is there a way that I can wait for `foo()` to finish running, including its `setTimeout` call, before `secondFunction()` fires? I suspect there is a way to do this with Promises because I've seen this problem solved with Promises before, however all the solutions I've seen includes tampering with the initial function that has the `setTimeout`; in my situation I cannot alter `foo()` at all.

Is there a way to solve this problem without altering `foo()` at all? This means I can't create Promises inside `foo()` nor can I add a callback function to `foo()` explicitly.

Comment: *"in my situation I cannot alter foo() at all."* Then you are out of luck.

Comment: Unless of course `foo` triggers some other function or event you could subscribe to. But I guess that's not the case?

Comment: What about adding a call back to the second function? It'll throw it on the alternate stack behind the foo setTimeout. Then the event loop will kick in when the stack clears, adding the next item in its que to the stack.

Comment: If function `foo()` changes something that can be accessed from outside of this function, you can set an interval that checks those changes, and fire `secondFunction()` if they are done. But is not a good practice for sure.

Comment: @FelixKling `foo()` is essentially an independent function that I can not alter at all, and once it is executed, `secondFunction()` is supposed to fire once `foo()` has completely finished. I'm basically trying to figure out if there's some way that I can tell when `foo()` has truly completed (with `setTimeouts` included) so I can call `secondFunction()`. I'm aware there may be no solution without explicitly altering `foo()` and I may have to rethink my approach, but if there is a solution then it'd be great.

Comment: Like Felix Kling said, if there is nothing triggered inside foo() then there is nothing to be checked.  If you simply can not change foo() (for business reasons), you can overwritten foo() with your own copy (complete duplicate from the original) and make the necessary change.  That is foo() is small and easily duplicate.

Comment: @Leng actually, you _can_ indirectly change `foo()`, by changing its view of what function is referenced via `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monkey-patch `setTimeout` because it's a property of the global object:

```
function trapTimeout() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
        window.setTimeout = function(cb, delay) {
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
            setTimeout.call(window, function() {
                window.setTimeout = setTimeout;
                cb.apply(null, args);
                resolve();
            }, delay, ctx);
        }
    });
}

var trap = trapTimeout();
foo();
trap.then(function() { console.log('really done') });
```

This is a moderately nasty hack.  It could well barf if something else creates a timer after this code (since the `.then` call doesn't stop any following code or the event loop from running, and the monkey patching remains in place until after the timeout is triggered).

Comment: Unfortunately the delay in my example is arbitrary